# Create enum from a c++ file at compile time

Tags: c++, enums, metaprogramming, preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I have some functions that can be defined by users like :

```
int prop1(....) {
  if(...)
    return Prop2;

   return Failed;
}

int prop2(...) {
  if(...)
    return Prop3;

  return Failed;
}
```

I want to create a file if the dependencies between the different functions.

Is there some way to generate a Enum at compile time and parse the file with some kind of regex to extract the different return tokens in a function and write it to a file.

Comment: Although some of these details are somewhat unclear, it is fairly common for large libraries to include small amounts of autogenerated code. You just have to write the code to do it. No autogenerated code is alike, and there is no universal tool of some kind, with a button that, once pushed, causes a script to come out that does this for you. You have to implement it yourself.

Comment: you can't do it. try writing a script

Comment: "I want to create a file if the dependencies between the different functions": please proofread.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create an `enum` at compile time.

You can parse the file before and create a file.h from it so that you can include it in your program, but nothing else.

Obviously you can automate this mechanism with a script.